# Automatically break on exception only reported in Visual Studio output?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm having trouble finding the origin of an exception in a C++ project.  When I run the executable natively everything appears fine.  When I run it from within Visual Studio I see some exceptions thrown in the Output window (copied below) but it still exits with code 0.  I've wrapped the entire main() function in a try/catch but nothing is caught and everything appears to be running smoothly.  Is there some mechanism in Visual Studio to force it to automatically break as soon as it detects one of the reported `std::out_of_range` exceptions?  I've already enabled `<All C++ Exceptions not in this list>` and `std::exception` in Visual Studio's Debug->Windows->Exception Settings.

```
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\path\to\MyApp\Debug\MyApp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
....Lots of Windows dlls and my dependencies....
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. 
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
The thread 0x3bf4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC97839689 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x000000369D91E170.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC97839689 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x000000369D91DF90.
The thread 0x6c24 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x747c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6ebc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6668 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6968 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4c48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10084] MyApp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently listing out exceptions like that in the Output window is expected behavior.  This simple program caused similar output.  I expected Visual Studio to only log exceptions like that if they were uncaught.  My assumption was incorrect.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    try
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {

    }
}
```